# PHP: Hide exception throw message

Tags: php

You may think its a stupid question. But I need this. Is it possible to hide exception throw message. I am experiencing some problems with exception message, actually it is very important thing at the time debugging, But in my case I don't want to display them anymore

Is there any way like php display_errors off ?

Comment: put this in the first line of your code `error_reporting(0);`

Comment: JFGI - http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php

Answer (score 3):

Add `ini_set('display_errors', false);` at the beginning.

You'd better not turn off error_reporting by `error_reporting(0);`, you need to check the error msg in log and had better to fix the error.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) function to enable / disable what errors appear. The PHP man page has examples of the various options available, you probably want this:

```
// Turn off all error reporting
error_reporting(0);
```

If there is a specific part of your code that is throwing an exception, you may wish to use a [try / catch block](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) to handle it rather than blocking it out.

If you have a production server, you may wish to turn off *displaying* errors but still record them. Changing the [configuration file](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php) on the server and setting `display_errors` to 0 is ideal since then you can keep your code identical between servers.

Answer (score 0):

`error_reporting(0);`

and/or

You can also write your error message into a txt file for example in the catch block (without displaying it on your screen)